# How to set href in single page javascript/html5 applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html, backbone.js

I have built a "small" single page web application using python/django/backbone (it's roughly equivalent to a simple Todo List app).

But I haven't solved the problem of having all `href` attributes set (for SEO purposes) and yet prevent users' browsers from reloading the entire app at a new URL.

A boiled down example of the problem:

Given this html snippet which cannot be subtracted from (*can* be added to):

`<a href="/myaccount/" >My Account</a>`

how can you achieve the following when a user clicks on the `a` element:

1. Do **not** send a request to server for /myaccount/
2. Do update the browser address to http://www.example.com/myaccount/

The solution doesn't need to rely on any existing features of backbone. I've assumed requirement (2) *does* require HTML5 which is fine.

A note on researching this question: I have done the usual googling around to find a common idea in most solutions for this. The main idea is to use `onclick` in the `a` elements **instead** of setting `href` and then take advantage of HTML5's pushstate API, but this is not a solution for my question. By experimenting with this solution I found that having `href` set caused the browser to send off a request for /myaccount/ regardless of what I put in on `onclick`.

Comment: Share your code, these things should be taken care by Backbone Router and Backbone.History

Comment: Possibly related for backbone https://gist.github.com/ssafejava/8394497

Comment: please confirm that you want all the relative links to be converted absolute links or sending request not to server only to client?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the HTML-Code snipplet provided is part of a Backbone View, ie. in form of a template. First, add a selector that makes sense to your code, like a class:

```
<a href="/myaccount/" class="navigation-element" >My Account</a>
```

Then, in your Backbone View add an event handler and use the preventDefault() Method for preventing propagation of the click event:

```
events: {
    'click .navigation-element': 'onNavigationElementClick'
},
onNavigationElementClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Here comes your magic */
},
```

The imporant bit here is the catching of the event and preventing the browser from following the link. This is done with the preventDefault method.